# Spring - Unable to get the view name set in ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

In Controller I set a code like this (this is the code called upon clicking submit inside a form)

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/Registration.htm"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Map<String, Object> userinfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        userinfo.put("NAME", request.getParameter("STUD_NAME"));
        userinfo.put("AGE", request.getParameter("STUD_AGE"));
        userinfo.put("ADDRESS", request.getParameter("STUD_ADDRESS"));

        // name of jsp/html 
        return new ModelAndView("hello","USERINFO", userinfo);
    }
```

the page should be looking for 'hello.jsp' but instead I got an error like this..

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCBaselineDynamic/WEB-INF/jsp/Registration.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /SpringMVCBaselineDynamic/WEB-INF/jsp/Registration.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.
```

it was looking for Registration.jsp.. do you know how to fix this one?
thanks

**web.xml**

```
   <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>


        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.controller"/>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Are you sure your request is actually hitting your controller method. Maybe its going through another handler. Add some logging to your controller method so you can verify

Comment: hi sir, yes sir it was hitting the controller method.. when I try to debug it, it actually goes in that method

Comment: thanks... I've already fix this one.. the problem is the ModelAndView I used.. it should be in servlet not in portlet :)))

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in your form and you are not calling this controller. I think you either are calling a controller that doesn't exist or trying to get a JSP that doesn't exist directly from the form.

Check your form, I guess the problem could be in the action. Also make sure you are making a POST call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is generated from '/Registration.htm' you are requesting to give you a .htm file while in your configuration you have set it to .jsp file that's why is returning the error  ***HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCBaselineDynamic/WEB-INF/jsp/Registration.jsp*** because the viewresolver is trying convert anything after the dot in your request mapping value to jsp.

Check your request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/Registration.htm"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
```

You should try changing it to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/Registration"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
```

I think that should work since your configuration is all working.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) yet ur suggestion is still not working

Comment: try changing your servlet-mapping to this : 
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for helping .. I already know the problem..

the ModelAndView I used is in portlet component.. it should be **servlet** ..